# How to aggregate over map keys across all the documents in mongodB collection?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in the following format:

```
[{
"OrderId": "406-5309498-5972326",
"revenueHeader": {
"Principal": 982.14,
"Product Tax": 117.86,
"Total": 1100
}},
{
"OrderId": "506-5234568-5934567",
"revenueHeader": {
"Principal": 382.54,
"Product Tax": 34.46,
"Shipping charge": 30.5,
"Giftwrap charge": 27.5,
"Total": 234
}}]
```

How can I sum the revenueHeader map values for the keys across all the documents? 
**Note:** "Shipping charge" is not present in the first document but we still want the sum for this key across all the documents. Also, the keys can vary, there is no way to know the name of keys beforehand.

Comment: Are these two records of a collection?

Comment: Also, post the expected result of these records and what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to transform revenueHeader in an array of {k,v} object.

You can then $unwind the array, and group by revenueHeader.k, summing revenueHeader.v . By this way, you never take care of the fields name or presence inside revenueHeader.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      revenueHeader: {
        $objectToArray: "$revenueHeader"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$revenueHeader"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$revenueHeader.k",
      total: {
        $sum: "$revenueHeader.v"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eh-nBCCn2eq)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly I was looking for but do you know if I can change this back to object. Specifically to LinkedHashMap (I want to maintain the order) or I will have to do it in Java?

Comment: what do you need as result? Ordered by what?

Comment: Actually I am confused about what would be better in performance. Should I fetch all the data from dB and do operations(sum) in mid-tier (Java) or directly do aggregation at the dB? Do you have any idea what would be better in performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about how many fields are going to be there for which you want to get the sum of values across documents then you can go with the solution given by @matthPen.

But if you know all the possible fields present then you can use directly use the $group stage with key names. As I personally avoid using $unwind if number of documents is very large.

```
[ 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: null,
            "Principal": { $sum: "$revenueHeader.Principal" },
            "Product Tax": { $sum: "$revenueHeader.Product Tax" },
            "Shipping charge": { $sum: "$revenueHeader.Shipping charge" },
            "Giftwrap charge": { $sum: "$revenueHeader.Giftwrap charge" },
            "Total": { $sum: "$revenueHeader.Total" },
        } 
    } 
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am confused about what would be better in performance. Should I fetch all the data from dB and do operations(sum) in mid-tier (Java) or directly do aggregation at the dB? Do you have any idea what would be better in performance?

Comment: Doing aggregation in MongoDB is always going to be the preferred choice over fetching data from DB to Java and then processing it by iterating over each record. As databases are developed with keeping these kinds of operation in mind. Performing aggregation in the Database is going to be faster any day in most of the cases as even your schema is also quite simple.